# Word for the amount of meaningful data in an array

Tags: naming-conventions

Not sure if this is the right place to post this, but is there a word for the amount of meaningful data in an array? "Size" or "width", to me, tends to mean the amount of memory allocated to the array but has no relavance to the amount of meaningful data inside. (Am I totally wrong here)? I have been using "population", but this doesn't seem quite right, and is quite confusing when programming genetic algorithms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about `elements` or `records`?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: The question was, "is there a word for the amount of meaningful data in an array?", and I believe I've provided an answer.  The question itself might not be appropriate for SO, but my response answers it.

Comment: OK, you're right given this context (your answer came with the 'low quality' review queue). Though note, I close voted the question now as 'primarily opinion based'. ([tag:variable] naming looks a bit contraditionary for the general rules of the site IMHO)

Comment: Agreed, and I've voted to close as well.